# Overview over not empty Cols by name by Grouping in R data frame

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I have a question that seems simple to me, but I can't solve it in R.

I have a data set of products with a classification and multiple characteristic columns. There I would like to group the data record according to classification and have the characteristics output that are not NA.

i.E.:

| Classification | characteristics 1 | characteristics 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | value1 | value1 |
| Type2 | NA | value2 |
| Type1 | value2 | value3 |
| Type2 | NA | value4 |

The expected result looks like:

| Classification | characteristics |
| --- | --- |
| Type1 | characteristics 1 |
| Type1 | characteristics 2 |
| Type2 | characteristics 1 |

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

Using the `dplyr` approach:

```
df <- tibble(Classification=c('Type1','Type2','Type1','Type2'),
           characteristics1=c("value1",NA,"value2",NA),
           characteristics2=c('value1','value2','value3','value4'))

df_new <- df %>% 
           pivot_longer(-Classification,
                        names_to='characteristics',
                        values_drop_na=TRUE) %>% 
           select(-value) %>% 
           distinct(Classification,characteristics)
```

That gives out

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Classification characteristics 
  <chr>          <chr>           
1 Type1          characteristics1
2 Type1          characteristics2
3 Type2          characteristics2
```

`Type2` is different but "characteristics1" is NA in both rows from your sample data and you were asking for non-`NA` cases.